# switching from twocolumn to onecolumn in LaTeX without pagebreak using package geometry

Tags: two-column, multicol, geometry

I am writing an article in a journal using a class file (WileyNJD-v2.cls) which uses geometry but I want to have a enumerated list over one column which starts at the place of the twocolumn (after prettying it) and then continues it over two pages and then switches back to two columns.

I have the following example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
      \textcolor{orange!50!black}\blindtext[1]
    \item \textcolor{blue!50!black}\blindtext[2]
    \item \textcolor{green!50!black}\blindtext[3]
    \item 
      \textcolor{orange!50!black}\blindtext[4]
    \item \textcolor{blue!50!black}\blindtext[5]
    \item \textcolor{green!50!black}\blindtext[6]
    \item 
      \textcolor{orange!50!black}\blindtext[7]
    \item \textcolor{blue!50!black}\blindtext[8]
    \item \textcolor{green!50!black}\blindtext[9]
    \end{enumerate}
  }
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

What I get is the attached pdf (well in three pngs), as follows: [image: first page] [image: second page] [image: third page]
Note that the png may not come across that clear, but basically, this is what happens. The two-column text ends the column, then goes to the next column and spans the first column over the page. It goes on beyond the page (because the text to be put in one column is also long) and then goes back to one column in the next page. How can I get the two-column to be such that it first adjusts and spans over two columns and then starts the one-column text over two columns and continues on to the next page? Many thanks for any help, and please let me know if something needs more clarification.

Comment: If I understand what you want, you can use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: Thanks, @Bernard. A simple \begin{strip} \end{strip} solves the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, thanks to @Bernard, is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,cuted}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{strip}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
      \textcolor{orange!50!black}\blindtext[1]
    \item \textcolor{blue!50!black}\blindtext[2]
    \item \textcolor{green!50!black}\blindtext[3]
    \item 
      \textcolor{orange!50!black}\blindtext[4]
    \item \textcolor{blue!50!black}\blindtext[5]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{strip}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```